# make mvc controller return text instead of json

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am trying to make method Spring MVC method in controller to return `text` instead of `json`.

My current method looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public ModelAndView uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    LOGGER.debug("Attempt to upload file with template.");
    try {
        String fileContent = FileProcessUtils.processFileUploading(file);
        return createSuccessResponse(fileContent);
    } catch (UtilityException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to process file.", e.getWrappedException());
        return createResponse(INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But the response header `content-type: application/json`.

I was trying to pass `HttpServletResponse` to controller and set content type but it still continued to return `json`.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity foo() throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body("response");
}
```

or do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
```

Both works fine.

Comment: user `responseEntity` instead of `ModelAndView`? Second solution does not work

Comment: Well, `ResponseEntity` works fine. You are making http call after all.

Answer (score 0):

What's FileProcessUtils?  Google doesn't bring up anything.  Is it a class created by you or your organization?  It would appear that the method is returning a response with a content-type of application/json.  What were you expecting it to return and why?  You would have to somehow parse the json to extract the data necessary for constructing a ModelAndView or find another method that returns what you want.

But without more information on FileProcessUtils, it isn't possible to provide more of an answer.

Comment: `FileProcessUtils` is just my own utility class. Basically in that case  it just the call `return new String(file.getBytes())`. I was expecting to return `json` but it seems ie9 has some problems to deal with it

Comment: Well that's where the problem lies.  You probably need to move the RequestMapping annotation with its "produces" clause over to there because nothing in the code you have shown us transfers this information to FileProcessUtils.processFileUploading().

Comment: Sorry. I don't get the idea. What's the purpose to move annotation to utility class?

Comment: To make the utility class method return what you are expecting it to.  That's not the only way.  Perhaps you ought to post the code to FileProcessUtils since we can only guess what might be in it.

Comment: But I expect `ModelAndView` to return `text` and not utility class. After all it could return any object as well...

Comment: ModelAndView doesn't RETURN anything.  It's a class, not a method.  Your problem seems to be that the method createSuccessResponse() which I am presuming you wrote is expecting text and you are sending it json.  So you have to either make processFileUploading() return text or parse the json in createSuccessResponse().  But without seeing what your code does, it's impossible to tell the best way.